# Find and replace in Notepad++

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

I have a big price list where i have to replace all prices by 0.
The price list is build by this style .

```
<Cost dollar="155"/>
<Cost dollar="240"/>
```

And i want to replace the numbers by 0 .

My attempt:

```
<Cost dollar="([0-9])"/>
```

EDIT :

solved by

```
<Cost dollar="([0-9]*)"/>
```

Comment: seems like a pretty simple regex. Have you tried any yet?

Comment: Yes i tried 
<Cost money="([0-9])"/>

Comment: That only matches 1 digit. Try putting an `*` after the `[0-9]`

Comment: You should give Peter's answer below a check mark then. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find: `\d*`

Replace: 0

Or use what you already did with the asterisk `[0-9]*`